# How do I edit the attributes of an NSAttributedString?

Tags: html, ios, swift, nsattributedstring

I want to be able to edit the HTML I get from my api request, changing the font and increasing among other things.

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url!) {(data, response, error) in
    var dataString:String = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)! as String
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

        var attributedString:NSAttributedString = NSAttributedString(data: data, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!

        self.textView.attributedText =  attributedString
    }
}
```

Comment: You have to use `NSMutableAttributedString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access the properties correctly you should be using an `NSMutableAttributeString`.

Change your String instantiation to this:

```
var attributedString: NSMutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(data: data, options:[NSDocumentTypeDocumentAttribute:NSHTMLTextDocumentType, NSCharacterEncodingDocumentAttribute: NSUTF8StringEncoding], documentAttributes: nil, error: nil)!
```

And add an attribute like so:

```
mutableString.addAttribute(NSFontAttributeName, value: UIFont(name: "Avenir", size: 18.0)!, range: NSRange(location:2,length:4))
```

This is just an example, you can create your own attributes to suit your needs.